# trying to run libreoffice calc basic macro stock.ods

Tags: software-installation, java, libreoffice, openjdk

I am a relative newbie with Linux, so I would appreciate kind words.
I will try to provide all the details.

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS.
May or may not have anything to do with the problem.

I downloaded stock.ods from l[ibreoffice SDK webpage](http://api.libreoffice.org/examples/examples.html#Basic_examples).

I installed default JRE.

When I run the macro, I get this error message:

```
LibreOffice 5.1.4.2
BASIC runtime error.
An exception occurred 
Type: com.sun.star.container.NoSuchElementException
Message: .
```

It appears that the error is in UpdateChart.
So, I commented out the call to that function, and ran it again.

Then, I get this error message:

```
LibreOffice 5.1.4.2
JAVA Is Not available
```

---

In a terminal window:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-8u111-b14-2ubuntu0.16.04.2-b14)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

And in LibreOffice calc, if I look under **tools->options->advanced**
I see the *Use a Java Runtime Environment** check box is checked.
And the JRE is listed as:

```
Vendor:  Oracle
Version:  1.8.0_111
```

---

I do not have the `Enable experimental features` checkbox checked.
I do not have the `Enable macro recording (limited)` checkbox checked. 
I didn't set anything under the Expert Configuration button.

---

So, what do I need to do in order to get the macro to run properly?